# Hibernate Session Factory issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 4 for building an application. While running the application I am getting the following error.

> Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   TRACE Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

My code snippet is,

```
try{
        session =  new DBConnection().getSession();
        tx= session.beginTransaction();

                ........

                ........

}catch(HibernateException ex)
    {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        session.close();
        DBConnection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        session.close();
    }
    finally{
        session.close(); // The error is shown in this line while run time
        DBConnection.close();
        }
```

DBConnection.java

```
public  DBConnection()
       {

                try
                { 
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.configure();
                    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry(); 
                    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

                }
                catch (Throwable ex) { 
                    System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
                }
       }

    public Session getSession() 
    {
          return factory.openSession();
    }



   // Call this during shutdown
   public static void close() {
        factory.close();
   }
```

My configuration file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">



<hibernate-configuration>


   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      test
   </property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">40</property>  

</session-factory>


</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please guide me what is wrong with the code or any jar file?

**

> Answer: The log4j is the cause of this issue. I removed the Log4j and
>   added log4j-1.2.16.jar. It gets fixed. Thanks!

**

Comment: how are you creating sessionFactory? where is you hibernate conf file located?

Comment: where is DBConnection.java

Comment: It is located in ROOT/WEB-INF/classes path

Comment: @rahul I have added the DBConnection.java file now pls check

Comment: add your configuration file as well to question. I mean .properties file

Comment: @Pokuri..you mean hibernnate.cfg.xml?

Comment: yes! that will show us what parameters you are configuring as well

Comment: @Pokuri I have added that file too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The log4j is the cause of this issue. I removed the Log4j and added
>   log4j-1.2.16.jar. It gets fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your code what is new DBConnection() refers. We need to get/open session in Hibernate from org.hibernate.SessionFactory.SessionFactory. So please check whether you are using sessionfactory or not.

Comment: Hi Balakrishna thanks for ur reply ..please find the DBConnection.java file in the edited question

Comment: I am using sessionfactory(pls refer the code snippet above). It is not fixed yet.

Comment: Please try the following codeConfiguration configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.configure();
                    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

Answer (score 0):

pls try

```
Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this code bt not gets fixed .

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling 2 times `session.close();`. 
In 2 `catch` clause and in the `finally` clause
Here :

```
catch(HibernateException ex)
{
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    ex.printStackTrace();
    session.close(); <--- 
    DBConnection.close();
}
```

and here :

```
finally{
    session.close(); <-----
    DBConnection.close();
    }
```

Remember, in java in the try-catch-finally statement, the `finally` will be executed whether an exception is thrown or not. In your case, if an exception is raised, `session.close()` will be called 2 times. One time in the `catch` clause and the second in the `finally` clause. I don't know how hibernate behave when you are calling 2 times `session.close()`

Comment: I agree with this.I change the code and tried, it is not working :(

Comment: Can you give the full exception stack, whithout it we I won't be able to give you an answer?

Comment: yep sure..I am getting only the following error: Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Test.java(line showing error I mentioned in the code)

Comment: Do you have mapping classes? Are you sure that there no exception has been raised before the finally? As I said, you are calling session.close 2 times. Make sure you call it only once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dimitri..The problem is coz of log4j.I updated it in my question.Thanks yar

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html) prefix your show_sql, format_sql and use_sql_comments with hibernate.
like

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
```